# What is the position of 'that' in the relative clause of this sentence?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory, relative-clauses, transformational-grammar

Researchers report they have engineered an enzyme **that** can convert 90% of that same plastic back to its pristine starting materials.

Does **that** originate in spec TP and move to spec CP like in this sentence? 
[image]

Comment: Could you please share book title?

Comment: It's Analysing English Sentences second edition by Andrew Radford

Comment: "That" is of course a subordinator, not a relative pronoun. Since the relativised element is subject of the relative clause, gap is located immediately after "that": "Researchers report they have engineered an enzyme [that ____ can convert 90% of that same plastic back to its pristine starting materials]"

Comment: For many English speakers _that_ is a subordinator; but for many it is also a relative pronoun that can be the subject of a relative clause like this. English has no ISO standards for parsing, and if it did, we'd ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between wh-relative clauses (1) and that-relative clauses (2). The first are formed by wh-movement, whilst the second are a result of a complementizer merged in the head of C:

(1) They said [CP that [TP they know [CP **who** [C ∅ [TP found the solution]]]]]. 
(2) They said [CP that [TP they know the key [CP [C **that** [solves the problem]]]]].

The wh-part in (141) (from Radford's book) is an adjunct. The wh-adjunct *which* is extracted from an A'-position will land in an A'-position (intermediate Spec,CP). This is how relative clauses such as (1) and (141) are formed.

However, (2) is formed by merging *that* in the head of C. There's no movement involved. Notice that in (1), the subject of the embedded verb *find* is **who**. **who** in this case is a subject-wh element. *who* may act as a subject and an object in other sentences. *that* cannot because it's a head. Head do not act subjects or objects.

Notice further that in (1), the wh-subject acts as a subject of the embedded TP **who found the solution**. In (2), the subject of this embedded clause (i.e., solves the problem) is the moved DP **the key**. Based on this, **that** in your sentence is a head not a specifier.

Researchers report [CP [TP they have engineered an enzyme [CP [C **that** [TP can convert 90% of that same plastic back to its pristine starting materials]]]]].

Do not take these labels for granted, the CP *that can convert 90% etc.* is an adjunct modifier of the NP enzyme. CP modifiers do no necessarily contain subjects.

Comment: If the relativised element is subject, there is no movement. The relative clause is not an adjunct, but a modifier in NP structure. Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure.

Comment: The embedded clause is a matrix in, e.g., who do you trust most?, this is formed by wh-movement of who (an object in this case). The same rationale carries over to complex sentences, e.g., I know the man who you trust most. The theta structure of this sentence presupposes an object of trust. I trust X. X is who which was moved. This again carries over to subjects, I believe.

Comment: Thank you so much, but is it possible for spec TP to be unoccupied? Does it need some kind of PRO subject?

Comment: PRO subject is required only in infinitival TPs, e.g., She wants [CP C[TP **PRO** to leave]]. In your sentence, we could put it this way: Researchers report [CP [C [PRO to have engineered an enzyme that can convert...etc.]]].

Comment: In "Who do you trust most?", "who" is a **prenucleus** linked to a 'gap' in object function. I think this analysis is better than invoking arcane theoretical concepts and formalisms.